# How to change datepicker cell style when it is not non accessible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have found similar questions on stackoverflow, but all the solution provided change style while it is not accessible like [here(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pjJGf/)
how to apply style when it is clickable

```
    $("#setDateTo").datepicker({
        defaultDate: date,
        minDate: "-0d",
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: changestyle
    });

  function changestyle(){          
     var day = date.getDay();
     if(date.getDate() == 12 || date.getDate() == 22)
      return[true, 'mystyle', 'changed'];
       else return[true, ''];
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to apply style when it is clickable....

You can set the color attribute to all anchor elements in table cell not having the class **ui-datepicker-unselectable**

```
td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable) a {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

```js
$('input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: "-0d",
    maxDate: "+90d",
    firstDay: 0,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates,
    beforeShow: function (inp, inst) {
        var a = this; // ui-datepicker-unselectable
    }
});

function noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates(date) {
    //var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return setHoliDays(date);
}

// set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay


function setHoliDays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    if (day == 5 || day == 6)
        return [false, ''];
    if (date.getDate() == 11 || date.getDate() == 23)
        return [false, 'holiday red', 'Red!'];
    if (date.getDate() == 12 || date.getDate() == 22)
        return [false, 'holiday green', 'Green!'];
    return [true, ''];
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
}
td.red span.ui-state-default {
    color: #f00;
}
td.green span.ui-state-default {
    color: #0f0;
}
td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable) a {
    color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
    <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to apply some style when date changes and matches your value.

[Check this.](http://jsfiddle.net/2t2qt4hv/)

On change event, `foo()` is called. Make your modifications inside that.

Comment: No, I need the cell to be changed, you see `td.red span.ui-state-default` that make changes only when it is not accessible, Probably I need another class, don`t know. Anyway thanks

Comment: Is [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/be5u4vgh/) what you need? Still not very clear to me.